# Compile Wordpress with HipHop

Tags: wordpress, hiphop

I have a high volume wordpress 3.2 installation. I was considering compiling wordpress in C++ with HipHop, as several resources report a speedup of up to 2.7x times with WordPress 3.0.

Anyhow I can't find any tutorial about wordpress 3.2.  Anyone have any experience?  Is there any problem I should expect?

If anyone could guide me with the compilation of wordpress, I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you doing all the other "normal" optimization basics - most prominently caching?

Comment: yes, the server has been optimized by an experienced sysadmin

Comment: You are also doing caching inside Wordpress? Using WP-Super-Cache or whichever plugin is most to your liking? (Because that is the optimization with the largest relative improvement)

Comment: I also use hardware acceleration for SSL and I/O...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a compiling wordpress subheader in the  [running hiphop-php wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop) under **Example: Compiling WordPress**. You might want to try that and ask more specific questions about problems that might come up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check this out.

http://huichen.org/en/2010/06/wordpress-three-hardened-by-hphp/

This is a pretty decent writeup to run WP 3 on ubuntu.

Thanks
Rajesh Pinapala